# Why I can't use & here

Tags: c

Please consider following code I wrote:

```c
    #include <stdio.h>
    typedef struct driver{
        char name[20];
        int dno;
        char rout[20];
        int expe;
    }drive;
    
    int main()
    {
        drive d[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            printf("Enter your name:");
            scanf("%s", d[i].name);
            printf("Enter your rout:");
            scanf("%s", d[i].rout);
            printf("Enter your driving licence number:");
            scanf("%d", &d[i].dno);
            printf("Enter your Exprinc in km:");
            scanf("%d", &d[i].expe);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            printf("***************************************************************\n");
            printf("Name of driver %d is %s \n", i+1, **d[i].name);**
            printf("Rout of driver %d is %s \n", i+1, **d[i].rout);**
            printf("driving licence number of driver %d is %d \n", i+1, d[i].dno);
            printf("exprence of driver %d  in km is  %d \n", i+1, d[i].expe);
            printf("***************************************************************\n");
            
        }
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Why I am unable to use `&` here? It gives warning like this:

```
warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[20]’ [-Wformat=]
   15 |         scanf("%s", &d[i].name);
      |                ~^   ~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 |   |
      |                 |   char (*)[20]
      |                 char *
travel_agency.c:17:17: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[20]’ [-Wformat=]
   17 |         scanf("%s", &d[i].rout);
      |                ~^   ~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 |   |
      |                 |   char (*)[20]
      |                 char *
```

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/), see [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and the documentation of your C compiler [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) then the documentation of your debugger [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/). Invoke GCC as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Answer (score 3):

By definition, `d[i].name` is the same as `&(d[i].name[0])` since in C, in many cases, an array decays into the pointer to its first element (of index 0).

For details, see  [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/), see [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c), and some recent C standard, such as [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or something newer such as [n2310](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2310.pdf)

Consider using [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/) or the [Clang static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) on your C source code.

Notice that [scanf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) can fail. You should test that, using the returned scanned item count. So code

```
    printf("Enter your name:");
    if (scanf("%s", d[i].name)<1) 
      perror("scanf name");
```

and in some cases, [printf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) could also fail.

Take inspiration by studying the source code of some existing [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html), such as [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/). Both might be useful to you.